# ¿como extraigo el primer registro asociado a diferentes CUSTOMER_ID?

Tags: sql-server, plsql

Necesito extraer las primeras facturas asociadas al customer_ID, es solo un ejemplo de una carga masiva de facturas asociadas a diferentes CUSTOMER_ID
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [ask]. En su formato actual, tu _pregunta_ parece más una solicitud para que alguien realice tu tarea escolar o trabajo. Te recomiendo que la edites y la enfoques a alguna duda particular y no simplemente presentar una solicitud y esperar el trabajo hecho. Es buena idea que expliques qué es lo que has investigado/intentado y el problema que actualmente impide que logres el objetivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las maneras de extraer los primeros, es utilizar la función de ventana Row_number

```
Create Table dbo.customers
             (
             customer_id Int
           , factura     VarChar(100)
           , ohrefdate   Date
           , ohduedate   Date
           , ohinvamt_gl Decimal(4, 2)
             );
Go
go
Insert into dbo.Customers (Customer_Id, Factura, OhRefDate, OhDueDate, OhInvAmt_Gl)
values
(42368648, 'T001-0020601556','20201128','20201217',0),
(42748333, 'T001-0029104586','20201222','20211001',30.88),
(42368648, 'T001-0031020314','20201228','20210117',49.89),
(42748333, 'T001-0039659235','20210122','20210210',47.88),
(42368648, 'T001-0041657284','20210128','20210217',40.57),
(42748333, 'T001-0050504241','20210222','20210310',-13.89),
(42368648, 'T001-0052528253','20210228','20210317',16.43),
(42748333, 'T001-0061625226','20210322','20210410',0);
GO
```

Con el escenario que has planteado.

```
With c
     As (Select *
              , Row_Number() Over(Partition By customer_id
                Order By customer_id
                       , ohrefdate
                       , factura) As row
                From dbo.customers)
     Select c.customer_id
          , c.factura
          , c.ohrefdate
          , c.ohduedate
          , c.ohinvamt_gl
            From c
            Where c.row = 1;
```

Sólo tienes que añadir la función row_number para numerar las filas, particionadas por cliente, y ordenadas por un criterio determinista. En este caso, como además de la fecha, tienes el número de factura es idóneo.

Del resultado, filtras las filas que quieres. Yo he puesto una sola fila. Pero el Wher c.row, podrían ser varias.

[image: Resultado]

[Row_number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!
Disculpa y como variaría el código aplicado a Oracle? solo en la función Row_number intercambiada por la función Rownum?

Comment: Oracle según la documentación posee la misma función. Revisa este link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm